# RTP audio stream player

Tags: java, audio, streaming, media-player, rtp

Can android supports audio rtp reading in native API?
I want to develop an rtp audio player, I have tried with:

MediaPlayer API : rtp does not work:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.androidmediaplayerexample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.*;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
//import java.lang.String;


import static android.util.Log.i;

public class AndroidMediaPlayerExample extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public TextView songName, duration;
    private double timeElapsed = 0, finalTime = 0;
    private int forwardTime = 2000, backwardTime = 2000;
    private Handler durationHandler = new Handler();
    private SeekBar seekbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //set the layout of the Activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize views
        try {
            initializeViews();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initializeViews() throws IOException {
        songName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songName);
        //mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample_song);


        //mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, myUri);
        try {
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.1.210:5000/test"); // initialize Uri here
            i("TestAudio", "URI : " + myUri.getScheme());
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("rtsp://192.168.1.210:5000/test");
            //mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // used for streaming
            //mediaPlayer.prepare(); //Message: Prepare failed.: status=0x1 Cause: null

            /*mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    //Called when the media file is ready for playback.
                    mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                            i("TestAudio","Percent : " + Integer.toString(percent));
                            if(percent == 100)
                            {
                                mp.start();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            i("TestAudio", "Message: " + e.getMessage() + " Cause: " + e.getCause());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        /*finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        songName.setText("Sample_Song.mp3");

        seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
        seekbar.setClickable(false);*/
    }

    // play mp3 song
    public void play(View view) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        /*timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
        durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);*/
    }

    //handler to change seekBarTime
    private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /*//get current position
            timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            //set seekbar progress
            seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
            //set time remaing
            double timeRemaining = finalTime - timeElapsed;
            duration.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining))));

            //repeat yourself that again in 100 miliseconds
            durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);*/
        }
    };

    // pause mp3 song
    public void pause(View view) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    // go forward at forwardTime seconds
    public void forward(View view) {
        /*//check if we can go forward at forwardTime seconds before song endes
        if ((timeElapsed + forwardTime) <= finalTime) {
            timeElapsed = timeElapsed + forwardTime;

            //seek to the exact second of the track
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
        }*/
    }

    // go backwards at backwardTime seconds
    public void rewind(View view) {
        /*//check if we can go back at backwardTime seconds after song starts
        if ((timeElapsed - backwardTime) > 0) {
            timeElapsed = timeElapsed - backwardTime;

            //seek to the exact second of the track
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.release();
    }

}
```

ExoPlayer API : does not support rtp and rtsp:

```
package com.ayalus.exoplayer2example;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Format;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.decoder.DecoderCounters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.LoopingMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoRendererEventListener;



/*
Created by: Ayal Fieldust
Date: 8/2017

Description:
This Example app was created to show a simple example of ExoPlayer Version 2.8.4.
There is an option to play mp4 files or live stream content.
Exoplayer provides options to play many different formats, so the code can easily be tweaked to play the requested format.
Scroll down to "ADJUST HERE:" I & II to change between sources.
Keep in mind that m3u8 files might be stale and you would need new sources.
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VideoRendererEventListener {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private PlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private TextView resolutionTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resolutionTextView = new TextView(this);
        resolutionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resolution_textView);

//// I. ADJUST HERE:
////CHOOSE CONTENT: LiveStream / SdCard
//
////LIVE STREAM SOURCE: * Livestream links may be out of date so find any m3u8 files online and replace:
//
////        Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("http://81.7.13.162/hls/ss1/index.m3u8"); //random 720p source
////        Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("http://54.255.155.24:1935//Live/_definst_/amlst:sweetbcha1novD235L240P/playlist.m3u8"); //Radnom 540p indian channel
//        Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("http://cbsnewshd-lh.akamaihd.net/i/CBSNHD_7@199302/index_700_av-p.m3u8"); //CNBC
        //Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("http://live.field59.com/wwsb/ngrp:wwsb1_all/playlist.m3u8"); //ABC NEWS
        Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.1.110/test"); //ABC NEWS
////        Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("FIND A WORKING LINK ABD PLUg INTO HERE"); //PLUG INTO HERE<------------------------------------------
//
//
////VIDEO FROM SD CARD: (2 steps. set up file and path, then change videoSource to get the file)
////        String urimp4 = "path/FileName.mp4"; //upload file to device and add path/name.mp4
////        Uri mp4VideoUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+urimp4);


        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter(); //test

        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector =
                new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        // 2. Create the player
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);

        int h = simpleExoPlayerView.getResources().getConfiguration().screenHeightDp;
        int w = simpleExoPlayerView.getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp;
        Log.v(TAG, "height : " + h + " weight: " + w);
        ////Set media controller
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(false);//set to true or false to see controllers
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        // Bind the player to the view.
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

        // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeter);
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
//        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(liveStreamUri);

        //// II. ADJUST HERE:

        ////        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeterA);
        ////Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
        //        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        //This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played:
        //FOR SD CARD SOURCE:
        //        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        //FOR LIVESTREAM LINK:
        MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
        final LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);
        // Prepare the player with the source.
        player.prepare(videoSource);

        player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onTracksChanged... ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPlayerStateChanged..." + playbackState+"|||isDrawingCacheEnabled():"+simpleExoPlayerView.isDrawingCacheEnabled());
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPlayerError...");
                player.stop();
                player.prepare(loopingSource);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true); //run file/link when ready to play.
        player.setVideoDebugListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onVideoEnabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoDecoderInitialized(String decoderName, long initializedTimestampMs, long initializationDurationMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoInputFormatChanged(Format format) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDroppedFrames(int count, long elapsedMs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged [" + " width: " + width + " height: " + height + "]");
        resolutionTextView.setText("RES:(WxH):" + width + "X" + height + "\n           " + height + "p");//shows video info
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenderedFirstFrame(Surface surface) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoDisabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

    }
//-------------------------------------------------------ANDROID LIFECYCLE---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.v(TAG, "onStop()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v(TAG, "onStart()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v(TAG, "onResume()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(TAG, "onPause()...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy()...");
        player.release();
    }
}
```

AudioStream API: rtp does not work:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.*;
import android.net.rtp.*;
import android.os.StrictMode;

import android.util.Log;

import java.net.*;

import static android.util.Log.i;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AudioStream audioStream;
    AudioGroup audioGroup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
        audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);
        InetAddress inetAddress;
        i("TestSon","aaaaa");
        try {
            inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.182");
            audioStream = new AudioStream(inetAddress);
            audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
            audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_RECEIVE_ONLY);
            InetAddress inetAddressRemote = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.210");
            audioStream.associate(inetAddressRemote, 6000);
            audioStream.join(audioGroup);

            i("TestSon","Local port : " + audioStream.getLocalPort());
            i("TestSon","Local address : " + audioStream.getLocalAddress());

            i("TestSon","Remote port : " + audioStream.getRemotePort());
            i("TestSon","Remote address : " + audioStream.getRemoteAddress());

        }
        catch ( UnknownHostException e ) {
            i("TestSon","exception1: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( SocketException e ) {
            i("TestSon","exception2: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

should I use an external lib like libvlc or ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FFmpeg to stream a single audio stream using the RTP protocol. Here is more information here:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#StreamingasimpleRTPaudiostreamfromFFmpeg

> FFmpeg can stream a single stream using the ​RTP protocol. In order to
>   avoid buffering problems on the other hand, the streaming should be
>   done through the -re option, which means that the stream will be
>   streamed in real-time (i.e. it slows it down to simulate a live
>   streaming ​source.
>
> For example the following command will generate a signal, and will
>   stream it to the port 1234 on localhost:
>
> ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i aevalsrc="sin(400*2*PI*t)" -ar 8000 -f mulaw -f
>   rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234 To play the stream with ffplay (which has
>   some caveats, see above), run the command:
>
> ffplay rtp://127.0.0.1:1234 Note that rtp by default uses UDP, which,
>   for large streams, can cause packet loss. See the "point to point"
>   section in this document for hints if this ever happens to you.